# How can I initialize lazy associations using Spring Data JPA when the query is specified in @Query annotation?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Here's my query *before* I converted over to Spring Data JPA.  Notice how I used to use `Hibernate.initialize()` to manually fetch the widget's messages.

```
public Object findWidget(final Widget findMe) {
    Widget widget = getJpaTemplate().execute(new JpaCallback<Widget>() {
        public Widget doInJpa(EntityManager em) throws PersistenceException {
            Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT h FROM " + entityClass.getName() + " h where h.widgetId = ? ");
            q.setParameter(1, findMe.getId());

            Widget found = (Widget)q.getSingleResult();

            //Initialize lazy associations
            if(found!= null){
                Hibernate.initialize(widget.getMessages());
            }

            return found;
        }
    });
    return widget;
}
```

And here's what my query function looks like now.  Notice there is no body to put the `Hibernate.initialize()` in.

```
@Query("SELECT h FROM Widget h where h.widgetId = ?1 ")
public AccessPoint findWidget(String widgetId);
```

So how can I specify that the widget's messages are to be fetched actively and not lazily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a fetch join, something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT h FROM Widget h LEFT JOIN FETCH h.messages WHERE h.widgetId = ?1 ")
public AccessPoint findWidget(String widgetId);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins

Comment: Thanks Mike, I didn't know about fetch joins.  I'm sure that will come in handy in the future!

Comment: @MikeN Do you know how to accomplish same thing by using Specifications API and Criteria API?

Comment: @svlada See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-dynamicfetching - I think you could have found that yourself too ;-)

Comment: @MikeN It's not possible with spring data

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can use Root.fetch() - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/FetchParent.html#fetch(javax.persistence.metamodel.PluralAttribute) - but I never used these APIs, especially not with Spring Data.

Answer (score 0):

Soon after I posted this question, I realized that I am trying to put functionality into the DAO layer that really belongs in the service layer.

So now I initialize the lazy associations using `Hibernate.initialize(widget.getMessages())`  in my `WidgetService` class, after I call `WidgetDAO.findWidget()`.

I really should have been doing it this way all along.

EDIT: @MikeN has a good point.  A **fetch join** is the real answer since it is implementation-independent and gets all necessary information in the original query.

Comment: You really shouldn't, since your explicit initialise makes your code Hibernate dependant, and is slower than the fetch join, since it does a separate query to initialise every connection (not entirely true with batch fetching).